# How load an annotation object on page load with annotator.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load an annotation object when page loads with annotator.js anyone knows how to?

Answer (score 1):

try to include

```
<script src="http://assets.annotateit.org/annotator/v1.2.5/annotator-full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://assets.annotateit.org/annotator/v1.2.5/annotator.min.css">
```

After that you just need to execute the annotator function on the needed part of your web page with Javascript. Just like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#my-div-that-should-be-annotated').annotator();
});
```

Comment: For further details: [Annotator manual about the setup](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you have stored the annotations, but this is how you would load them if you already have them on hand.

So after the page has loaded, add:

```
var ann = $(element).annotator();  
ann.annotator("loadAnnotations", comments);
```

where `comments` is an array of annotation objects as defined at:
http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/stable/annotation-format.html